# PHP - Multiple Sticky Checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery, webforms

there is a need to read  different jobs (e.g., job1, job2, job3, ... job n) from a database and place them on a form for a user to select those jobs a user likes through checkbox Selection as Shown below.

- ( ) Job 1 description1,
- (X) Job 2 description2
- (X) Job 3 description3
- :
- :
- ( ) Job N descriptionN

Given that the number of jobs can be too high for a single page to display, pagination is employed so that the whole form is broken into number of pages. the requirement is that a users's checknbox Selection on a given page has to be sticky even when a user navigates through different pages of this form. how to achieve this.

if JQuery can be of use to Simplify the task, please Show me As well.

I use the following code:

```
 function selected($job_id)
 {          
    if (empty($_POST['job_selection'])) || (!is_array($_POST['job_selection'])) ||       (!in_array($job, $_POST['job_selection'])) {
      return '1';
    }

    return 'checked';
  }    


     $q10 = "SELECT ...
 $r10 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q10);                                    
     if (mysqli_num_rows($r10) > 0) {

      while ($row10 = mysqli_fetch_array($r10, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
      {

       if (isset($_POST['job_selection'])){   
        $jid = $row10['job_id'];
            echo '<td align="left"><p class="normal_text"><input type="checkbox" name="job_selection[]" value="' . $row10['job_id'] . '" selected($jid) />' . $row10['job_name'] . '</p></td>';      
        } 
        else 
        {             
           echo '<td align="left"><p class="normal_text"><input type="checkbox" name="job_selection[]" value="' . $row10['job_id'] . '" />' . $row10['job_name'] . '</p></td>';               
        }
     } 
   }
```

The Issue is that when Navigating through pages by clicking the page number, the form is not necessarily Submitted - hence, $_POST['job_selection'] will be empty.

Comment: maybe you could provide relevant code you are using...

Comment: why can;t group the job based on the category? You can filter based on the category. No need to break the form into more than one page.

Comment: No, the requirement is to break the form into number of pages containing numerous checkboxes of the Same type. Consider an example where a user has to Select preferred car models out of many.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **client-side** pagination for your list.

There is a lot of simple jQuery plugins to achieve it : http://www.smashingapps.com/2013/05/06/16-beautiful-jquery-pagination-plugins.html